# Find wheel dependencies during an rpm build

Tags: python, ubuntu, rpm

The rpm build for the project I'm working on isn't finding dependencies, and I can't seem to figure out why. I've installed all of them to my virtual environment and they are all being saved in my defined wheel directory. I'm using the `rpmvenv` library to generate the rpm, but every time I run it from my setup script, it comes back with this:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.11.0 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy==1.11.0
```

If I do a `pip list` in my venv  though, that version of numpy is there, and the wheel for the package is also present. `rpmvenv` requires an `rpm.json` file to run, and in mine I have the line

```
"pip_flags": "--no-index --find-links=/path/to/wheel/directory"
```

in the `python_venv` extension. I'm under the impression that this line tells the build to look for dependencies in my wheel directory, but it can't find them. I've also tried to add the `--use-wheel` flag to this line, but to no avail.

What's the piece that I'm missing here?

Comment: You should probably install an RPM package for numpy 1.11.0 (and other dependencies) prior to building an RPM that requires it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pip and rpm use different dependecy resolver and db. If you install python module using pip, then rpm do not know about it. Rpm knows nothing about python paths and where it store modules. It just check rpmdb if python-numpy.rpm have been installed.

If you need that package you can find it here https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/neteler/numpy/